# Regular exspression to search string with number of space occurance

Tags: regex

I want to search where string with the following condition using a regular expression.

```
<Fixed-Word><up to 2 words><Fixed-Word>
```

Example of matching MaryAlen

Marry Alen - Valid

Marry Jhon Alen - Valid

Marry Jhon Alen - Valid

Marry Jhon David Alen - Valid

Marry Jhon Simon David Alen - Not Valid from now on

```
/(Marry)(\w{0,3}?)(Alen)/
```

I tried above regular expression but not working. basicallly i need regular expression which will check upto 2 words in between 2 fixed words.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you tried `(Marry)(\w{0,3}?)(Alen)` matches the 2 names and what is in between can be 0 - 3 times a word character (no space) and could for example match `MarryaaaAlen`

You could repeat a space and 1+ word chars in a group 0 - 2 times:

```
\bMarry (?:\w+ ){0,2}Alen\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/52oc3y/1)

If you want to match non whitespace chars instead of word characters, you could use:

```
\bMarry (?:\S+ ){0,2}Alen\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/52oc3y/2)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Since the text I am searching might contain characters from other languages it will not work for me. so I have modified bit and answered it here. Thanks again.

Comment: @RaghavendraC I have updated my answer using `\S` instead of `\w` See https://regex101.com/r/52oc3y/2

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, you might be interested in name validation of some kind, you might want to design an expression that would maybe look like:

```
^\s*(Marry)(?:\s*([\p{L}-]*)\s*){1,2}(Alen)\s*$
```

or:

```
(Marry)(?:\s*([\p{L}-]*)\s*){1,2}(Alen)
```

or:

```
(Marry)(?:\s*([\p{L}-]*?)\s*){1,2}(Alen)
```

if `\p{L}` might work OK.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XtYi2J/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/XtYi2J/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
Marry(\s*)(?:(\S*)(\s*)){0,2}Alen
```

This regular expression solved my issue. Thank you :)

Comment: I have updated my answer using `\S`. This pattern. This pattern could give you empty capturing groups See https://regex101.com/r/oAPMwV/1